# Is the location background mode not necessary for getting region events?

Tags: ios, background, gps, region, geofencing

I have an app that uses regions for unlocking data. The user can walk around in a specific city and unlock information about historic events by going to specific points in the city.

For this I'm using CLCircularRegion, and I enabled the location background mode to get notifications when the app isn't running. Just submitted the app to Apple earlier this week, and got a rejection today due to: "We noticed your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not include features that require persistent location. "

So is the location background mode not necessary for getting region changes? Or is this just a mistake by Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit back and forth it seems that you don't need the location background mode for region monitoring. If you enter or exit a region (assuming you've set triggers for both), the app will be launched in the background with the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey launch option.